# How to apply CSS only on devices with screen size less than 5 inches?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, media-queries

I am looking for a technique that will allow me to apply a certain CSS only if the current device (where my web-app runs) has a "small" screen – smaller than, say, 5 inches.

Some notes to make my question more clear:

- It should not be based on screen resolution or density, because there are some tablets that have a small resolution and some smartphones that have a high resolution.
- It also should not depend on current browser's window size. If it's a desktop then the CSS should not be applied even if the window was made small.
- My web-app has two layouts. One is default and is optimized for desktops and tablets. Another layout is optimized for smartphones and should only be turned on on smartphones.
- In my case nothing can be done on server-side. Different domains for each variant are not an option.

Thank you in advance!

**Update**

Here is a test page with my best try: http://jsbin.com/uXULOpe/2/

For Samsung Galaxy Nexus i9250 (4,5" sreen) it enables wrong style (".pad")... For iPad and WindowsPhone it seems to be working. Android seems to be thinking that it's width is at least 8 inches.

Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>M-Q test</title>

    <style>
        .always,
        .desktop,
        .pad,
        .smart{
            display: none;
        }

        .always{
            display: inline-block;
        }

        @media  only screen and (min-device-width : 10in) {

            .desktop{
                display: inline-block;
            }
        }

        @media  only screen and (min-device-width : 5in) and (max-device-width : 10in) {

            .pad{
                display: inline-block;
            }
        }

        @media  only screen and (max-device-width : 5in) {

            .smart{
                display: inline-block;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, height=device-height, maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>

    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />

</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li>Always: <span class="always">x</span></li>
        <li>Desktop: <span class="desktop">x</span></li>
        <li>Pad: <span class="pad">x</span></li>
        <li>Smartphone: <span class="smart">x</span></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I know about media queries, I cannot make them to do the work. In the internet most examples I've found are based on pixels. I've tried with inches (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width : 4.5in) "/>`) but it doesn't work on Android 4.3...

Comment: In that case, did you also include a meta viewport element?

Comment: @MrLister yes: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>`.

Comment: Have you experimented a bit with different values for `max-device-width` to find out if the phone responds to the query at all?

Comment: @MrLister yes. It will switch the CSS on if `max-device-width` is equal or greater than `8in`. That is wrong because it's screen size is 4,5 inches. The `min-device-width` is turning CSS on for values less than 8 inches. I think Android has bug there. iPad and WindowsPhone are working correctly... Here is my test page: http://jsbin.com/uXULOpe/1/ (to view source: http://jsbin.com/uXULOpe/1/edit)

Answer (score -2):

To use two Templates/Models/Propertys:

```
   //controll the browser size and set Propertys
    if( body.offsetWidth < 400 ){ /* Small Sized Propertys */ }
    if( body.offsetWidth >= 400 ){ /* Big Sized Propertys */ }
```

To set sizes dynamic, use jQuery:

```
//this starts on every browser resize interaction
$( window ).resize(function() { 

if( body.offsetWidth < 400 ){ /* Small Sized Propertys */ }
if( body.offsetWidth >= 400 ){ /* Big Sized Propertys */ }

});
```

But you need to include the jQuery Script in your Head. Its a big Framework.

Comment: jQuery is only 82kb which is not big at all to be implemented in a web page, I also feel like your answer doesn't answer the question at all, as this will not check the actual size of the device at all.

Comment: body.offsetWidth depends on the browser's window size, not the device screen size...